# Twilio Voice Insights anomalies

Tags: twilio

We are using iOS Client SDK and using Voice Insights to try to find out why we are having so many issues with call quality. Voice Insights is enabled. A few questions:

- The docs say the JS Client SDK is required for voice insights, and iOS support is in development. But we are using the iOS SDK and we are getting VI data. Is this data still reliable?
- I noticed starting sometime this weekend that we stopped getting data. Any idea why?
- We have gotten many constant_audio_input_level and constant_audio_output_level warnings, yet when I look at Metrics, for every call, even those where I know levels were changing and the mic was enabled, it shows a constant level of zero. Are these audio level warnings reliable, or should I ignore them for now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Development for iOS and Android SDKs is still in progress.

We recommend not using this data.

The constant-audio-io-level warnings are based on the metrics data, and since the metrics data is not available for iOS and Android, these warnings shouldn't be used until Twilio officially announces support for iOS and Android.